# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

In my android application, I am making service call using rest template, but the problem is now I am getting below error when any services get called. The services are not connecting to the server.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.lss.company, PID: 8611
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate
                  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:498)
                  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:447)
                  at com.lss.company.services.ServerAuthenticateService.getAllEmployeeList(ServerAuthenticateService.java:7320)
                  at com.lss.company.view.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:138)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5459)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the build.gradle dependency codes

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lss.company"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'

    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:2.0.0.M3'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There was no error till now and all of my services are working but suddenly this error came out and it's not allowing me to continue.Below is the call to the server.

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployeeList() {

    String plainClientCredentials="************************";
    String base64ClientCredentials = new String(Base64.encode(plainClientCredentials.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64ClientCredentials);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> restRes = restTemplate.exchange(LoginActivity.strMainUrl+"protected/users/getAllEmployeeList", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    System.out.println("restRes : "+restRes);
    if (restRes.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        AppBackupCache.checkToken = 200;
        String resBody = restRes.getBody();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Employee>>() {}.getType();
        List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        schoolList = gson.fromJson(resBody,listType);
        return employeeList;
    } else if(restRes.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
        AppBackupCache.checkToken = 401;
        return null;
    } else {
        AppBackupCache.checkToken = 402;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Above code was working fine till now and suddenly the error came and its not working,same happens in every service calls.What is wrong in my code.
Below is the way i am calling other services from activity classes.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginpage);
        this.progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        this.progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
        this.progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.accountManager = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());
        String accountName = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        this.authTokenType = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_AUTH_TYPE);
        this.edtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUserName);
        this.edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        this.edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        this.btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        this.btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        this.linLayMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLayMain);
        this.acTxtCompany = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acTxtCompany );
        if (this.authTokenType != null) {
            this.authTokenType = AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS;
        }
        if (accountName != null) {
            this.edtUserName.setText(accountName);
        } else {
            String lastUser = getSharedPreferences("version", 0).getString("userName", null);
            if (lastUser != null) {
                this.edtUserName.setText(lastUser);
            } else if (this.accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.lss.company").length > 0) {
                this.edtUserName.setText(this.accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.lss.company")[0].name);
            }
        }
        this.submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        this.submit.setOnClickListener(new C12411());
        if (AppBackupCache.isServerReachable(getApplicationContext())) {
        this.employeeList = serverAuthenticateService.getAllEmployeeList();
        if (AppBackupCache.checkToken == ItemTouchHelper.Callback.DEFAULT_DRAG_ANIMATION_DURATION) {
            showDepartmentSpinner();
        } else if (AppBackupCache.checkToken == 401) {
            this.manager.invalidateAuthToken("com.lss.company", this.authtoken);
            this.authtoken = null;
            final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = this.manager.getAuthToken(this.mAccount, AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, true, null, null);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Bundle bnd = (Bundle) future.getResult();
                        LoginActivity.this.authtoken = bnd.getString("authtoken");
                        if (LoginActivity.this.authtoken != null) {
                            LoginActivity.this.employeeList = serverAuthenticateService.getAllEmployeeList();
                            if (AppBackupCache.checkToken == ItemTouchHelper.Callback.DEFAULT_DRAG_ANIMATION_DURATION) {
                                LoginActivity.this.showDepartmentSpinner();
                                return;
                            }
                            LoginActivity.this.getMsgBox("Error", "Something went wrong");
                            return;
                        }
                        System.out.println("************** NULL *****************");
                        LoginActivity.this.getMsgBox("", "Token not refreshed....");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
        AppBackupCache.checkToken = 401;
        return;
    }
    getMsgBox("No connection", "No connection");

}
```

service class :

```
public class ServerAuthenticateService implements ServerAuthenticate {

  String authAToken = null;
  Gson gson;
  RestTemplate restTemplate;


  public List<Departments> getAllDepartmentList() {
      MultiValueMap headers = new HttpHeaders();
      System.out.println("authToken " + authToken);
      headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "bearer " + authToken);
      ResponseEntity<String> restRes = this.restTemplate.exchange(companyUrl + "protected/users/getAllDepartmentList", HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity(headers), String.class, new Object[0]);
      if (restRes.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
          AppBackupCache.checkToken = Callback.DEFAULT_DRAG_ANIMATION_DURATION;
          String resBody = (String) restRes.getBody();
          Type listType = new C07736().getType();
          List<Departments> catList = new ArrayList();
          return (List) this.gson.fromJson(resBody, listType);
      } else if (restRes.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
          AppBackupCache.checkToken = 401;
          return null;
      } else {
          AppBackupCache.checkToken = 402;
          return null;
      }
  }

  public ServerAuthenticateService() {
    try {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
            protected boolean hasError(HttpStatus statusCode) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {

            @Override
            public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

                String frStr = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
                Date retDate =null;
                try {

                    retDate = dtfDate.parse(frStr);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return retDate;
            }
        });
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                String jsDate = dtf.format(src);
                return new JsonPrimitive(jsDate);
            }
        });
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new JsonDeserializer<Timestamp>() {

            @Override
            public Timestamp deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
                String strDate = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = dtf.parse(strDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            }
        });
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, new JsonDeserializer<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
                return Base64.decode(json.getAsString(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            }
        });
        gson = builder.create();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

When i commented the oncreate code on activity named AttachmentActivity then the error on loginActivity disappears.The error is showing on LoginActivity because from there the first webservice call is happening, if i commented this line `this.employeeList = serverAuthenticateService.getAllEmployeeList();` then the error may appear on the next webservice call on the next activity.
`onCreate()` on `AttachmentActivity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView((int) R.layout.attachment_activity);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle((CharSequence) "Add staff");
    this.userId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("userId");
    this.companyId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("companyId");
    this.companyUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("companyUrl");
    this.screen = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("screen");
    this.manager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
    this.sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("version", 0);
    this.accNow = this.sharedPreferences.getInt("AccountNow", 0);
    this.childNow = this.sharedPreferences.getInt("ChildNow", 0);
    this.mAccount = this.manager.getAccountsByType("com.lss.company")[this.accNow];
    this.authtoken = this.manager.peekAuthToken(this.mAccount, AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS);
    this.fontFamily = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    this.edtSelDept = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSelDept);
    this.edtDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescription);
    this.edtLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLink);
    this.cardVwKeyPair = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardVwKeyPair);
    this.cardVwDocuments = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardVwDocuments);
    this.cardVwMedia = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardVwMedia);
    this.mSpnCategory = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mSpnCategory);
    this.frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
    this.fabMenu = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.fab_menu);
    this.fabAdd = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
    this.rcyAttachment = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyAttachment);
    this.rcyHorDocuments = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyHorDocuments);
    this.rcyMedia = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyMedia);
    this.mSpnType = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mSpnType);
    this.txtIpSelDept = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.txtIpSelDept);
    this.txtIpDescription = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.txtIpDescription);
    this.txtIpLink = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.txtIpLink);
    this.cardVwStaff = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardVwStaff);
    this.acTxtStaffId = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acTxtStaffId);
    this.btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    this.lvStaff = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvStaff);
    this.fabMenu.setVisibility(0);
    this.frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    fabMenu.setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener(new FloatingActionsMenu.OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuExpanded() {
            frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(200);
            frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    fabMenu.collapse();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuCollapsed() {
            frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
            frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }
    });
    this.mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    this.rcyAttachment.setLayoutManager(this.mLayoutManager1);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1) {
        this.rcyAttachment.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    } else {
        this.rcyAttachment.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    }
    this.rcyMedia.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, 1, false));
    this.rcyMedia.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    this.progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    this.progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
    this.progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
    this.fabAdd.setOnClickListener(new C09662());
    this.fabAdd.setVisibility(0);
    this.cardVwKeyPair.setVisibility(0);
    this.mSpnCategory.setVisibility(0);
    this.mSpnType.setVisibility(0);
    this.txtIpDescription.setVisibility(0);
    this.txtIpLink.setVisibility(0);
    this.categoryList = AppBackupCache.getCategoryList();
    if (this.screen == 1) {
        this.txtIpSelDept.setVisibility(0);
        getStaffDeptAndTypes();
        setupCategorySpinner();
    } else if (this.screen == 2) {
        this.cardVwStaff.setVisibility(0);
        getAllStaffAndTypes();
        setupCategorySpinner();
    }
    this.edtSelDept.setOnClickListener(new C09673());
    this.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new C09684());

}
```

Comment: The error is in LoginActivity Line 138. Can you specify what's the line?

Comment: can you add LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:138) code?

Comment: @JonathanJohx Updated the code with onCreate.One thing i noticed is when i commented the oncreate code in one of the other activity page the error dissappears.

Comment: Okay, please tell me exactly what is on line 138

Comment: Oh... sorry i was posted wrong code earlier...Following is the code on line 138 this.employeeList = serverAuthenticateService.getAllEmployeeList();

Comment: @JonathanJohx When i commented the oncreate code on activity named AttachmentActivity then the error on loginActivity disappears..

Comment: The error is showing on LoginActivity bcos from there the first webservice call is happening, if i commented this line this.employeeList = serverAuthenticateService.getAllEmployeeList(); then the error may appear on the next webservice call on the next activity.

Comment: What do you have on onCreate code on activiy called AttachmentActivity?

Comment: @JonathanJohx Updated the code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186397/discussion-between-jonathan-johx-and-kjejava48).

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: @JakeSteam No....

Answer (score 0):

You've missed out on including spring-web in your classpath. add it to your Gradle file and it should work.

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-web:<!--your spring version-->"
```

Comment: Is it ok to add compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.2.RELEASE' ??